# why Mongo sharding writin only single shard

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sharding

I have 2 shards replica set inside let's say shard1 and shard2 but when I try to create some docs only on shard1 do the job I check from htop in ubuntu server

e.g All server are seperated in different machine including with primary Replica and Secondary one

Comment: What is the maximum chunk size in your cluster?

Comment: Thank you for your response this is my chunk size 1024
{ "_id" : "chunksize", "value" : 1024 }
{ "_id" : "balancer", "mode" : "full", "stopped" : false }
{ "_id" : "autosplit", "enabled" : true }

Comment: chunksize is too big? I'm new to mongo